# Why is both my input array and output array corrupted when I try to implement a function to reverse the array?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I'm Programming in C, using Linux GCC Compiler. I'm very much new to programming.

I'm confused as to why my in[] char array would be changed at all in the function. Doesn't the code simply count the amount of subscripts in in[] and then copy its contents into out[] but backwards? How is it being changed in the function?

```
/*reverse in to out*/
void reverse(char in[], char out[]) {
    int i, l,b;
    b = i = l = 0;

    while (in[i] != '\0')
        ++i;

    for(l=i;l > 0; l--) {
        in[l] = out[b];
        ++b;
   }
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignment statement is backwards.

```
in[l] = out[b];
```

Means "Assign the value in array `out` at index `b` to array `in` index `l`". This line should instead be

```
out[b] = in[l];
```

And BTW, you don't need an empty `return` statement, you can simply omit this in a `void` function.

Comment: Thank you. This helped some but now out[] is empty.

Comment: Actually you can only omit the return at the end of the function because it will automatically return to its caller when reaching that point. If you want to return early then you must use it explicitly

Comment: Yup, thanks for your input, **It lead me to the fixing the function.** After this, the function was empty because in[l] should really start at in[l-1].

Either way, this answered the question. After implementing the change the in[] array was never changed thus not corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(l=i-1;l >= 0; l--) {
    out[b] = in[l];
    ++b;
}
out[b] = '\0';
```

Four problems fixed: start at `i-1`, test for `l>=0`, reverse the assignment, and terminate out with a null character.

Also, a good idea is to use `const` when a function argument will not be changed.  In this case, `const char in[]` would let you spot the assignment error because the compiler would give you a compile time error.

Comment: Sorry, should have been l, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen :

```
for(l=strlen(in), b=0; l>=0; l--)
    out[b++] = in[l];

// ensure null terminated so strlen out works
out[b] = '\0';
```

This assumes out is wide enough for in AND in is null terminated

Comment: This is the better way to do it but I'm only given a certain amount of functions to work with in K&R, for the reason of learning programming, I want to build my own functions from scratch, not rely on functions made by other people.

Either way, thank you.